# Hosting my Android application on git including its' libraries

Tags: android, eclipse, git, libraries, eclipse-adt

I am new to all the Android world. I want to make my application easy to start up after git clone. Currently I created an app that uses Google Services, Volley and other libraries. My git repository only includes the source code of my project excluding libraries. I tried to clone the project on another laptop and I had to go through the hassle of downloading and importing libraries on Eclipse ADT.

Is there some sort of convention for including libraries in a project repo? For example Rails has the `Gemfile` that would download all libraries after executing `bundle install` command.

Should I just make the whole workspace of the project (Which would also include my libraries) as my git repository? And when I clone the project on a new device I would switch the Workspace on Eclipse ADT.

What is the best practice for hosting Android application libraries on git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gradle build system used in new Android projects uses `build.gradle` files to declare dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '14.0.1'
... }
```

More info here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide